# Not able to call Native Method from Java Android cocos2d-x

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, native-code

I am trying to call a Native method which I have defined in a C class from a Java class in Android. Both the code is displayed below.

Cpp

NativeCall.h

```
// NativeCall.h
 #ifdef __cplusplus
#include "platform/android/jni/JniHelper.h"
#include "NativeInterface.h"
using namespace std;
 extern "C" {
 #endif 

 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_sugarcube_Connect_JniHelper_makeNativeCall(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring request)
 {
     string returnValue = NativeInterface::getInstance()->processApiCall(env->GetStringUTFChars(request,0));
     jstring str = env->NewStringUTF(returnValue.c_str());
     return str;
 }
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

NativeCall.cpp

```
#include "NativeCall.h"
```

Java Code

```
public String invokeNativeCall(String request){
        return makeNativeCall(request);
    }
    private native String makeNativeCall(String request);
```

PackageName : com.sugarcube.Connect
JavaClassName : JniHelper.java

Also I have added NativeCall.cpp to my android.mk file

Whenever I try to execute invokeNativeCall it bumps telling

```
JniHelper.makeNativeCall(String) line: not available[native method][local variables unavailable].
```

Any idea why this is happening?